# HTML Form with 2 list boxes

Tags: php, html, forms, listbox, submit

I have one listbox with value ('FirstValue', 'SecondValue', 'ThirdValue') and another one with ('D','E'). Now, I want to build a submit form with one submit button which POST one value from the first listbox and one value from the second listbox. How to do this with html and php? Can anyone give me an easy example?

Example first listbox -> SecondValue and Second listbox -> E.

After click on the submit button I need something like var = 'SecondValue', 'E'!

Comment: When you say list box do you mean a select element?

Comment: What you are describing is the default way `form`s work. If you use a `post` method in your form tag, your valueas will be available in `$_POST['fieldname']` in the php file you send it to.

Comment: I have at the moment something like this...                                                           <form id="center" Name="Form1" Method="Post" Action="">
 <select name="List1" Size="8">
     <option value="FirstValue">first Vallue</option>
     <option value="SecondValue">second Value SLK</option>
    </select>
   </br>
   <Input Name="S1" Type="Submit" Value="Show">
</form> But I need I need one more select element

Comment: Then you need to write another <select>-Element. Look here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help.

HTML Form:

```
<form action="f.php" method="post">
  <select name="lb1">
    <option value="FirstValue">FirstValue</option>
    <option value="SecondValue">SecondValue</option>
    <option value="ThirdValue">ThirdValue</option>
  </select>

  <select name="lb2">
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

f.php

```
<?php
  $var = array($_POST['lb1'], $_POST['lb2']);
?>
```